# Automatic role change for read/writes using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The addition of multiple databases on Rails 6.1 is great and provides a way to have a fairly [simple read from follower write on replica setup](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#activating-automatic-role-switching) if you use the included resolver.

That works if your app is fully RESTful and there's no mutations on the database during [GETs and HEADs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.7/activerecord/lib/active_record/middleware/database_selector.rb#L72-L74). On paper that's great but there are some situations where alterations of the data can happen (see consuming tokens, lazy cleaning data, set flags, etc).

[ActiveRecord knows when the query is a write](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fad500b8c62b053bcd1f8faf2a13f28d3def573f/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb#L207-L209) one and raises an error if the target connection is a replica one.

I want to automatically switch between leader and follower based on that condition. PGPool2 does that but I'd like to avoid setting up another service if it were possible.

A simple solution I tried was to create a custom resolver and wrap the execution but since ActiveRecord can detect a query that modifies the data I was wondering if there's any way to switch the connection before execution.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Middleware
  module DatabaseSelector
    class AutoSwitchResolver < ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
      def read(&block)
        super(&block)
      rescue ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyError
        write(&block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I also tried to hook up to `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter` `execute` methods [as Marginalia does](https://github.com/basecamp/marginalia/blob/master/lib/marginalia.rb) to try to overwrite the target without much luck.

EDIT:

I also tried and it seemed to work but it ends up failing alongside the stock Rails resolver:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  around_save :ensure_write_database
  around_destroy :ensure_write_database

  def touch(*args)
    ensure_write_database { super(*args) }
  end

  def ensure_write_database
    ApplicationRecord.connected_to(role: :writing) { yield }
  end
```